# Node JS Application debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I am new to to NODE JS. My Application is using express,grunt, mocha also. I just use grunt command and all the initial setup for running files is set. Now in one of the files for authentication, I need to see the request and the response object. One way I can just use console and keep digging but is there any way that I can print it in browser or in some tool where it will give me all the data in JSON format where I can inspect the req and res objects?

Comment: https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Comment: I am not getting it. I have a response object. All in JSON format which is in file router.js and in my grunt file all the setup is there to run the files. I just use grunt command to run the application. Now at some point it goes to the desired file and have that req and res object. I want to print that res object in chrome so that I can easily check that whole object.